# La piramide no sale como piramide JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un ejercicio de crear una piramide por consolaa, le digo un numero y tiene que crearse una piramide de asteriscos.

La verdad que no esta 100% hecho por mi pero he intentado entender las cosas pero no soy capaz de que forme una piramidee.

que me falta?

codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Piramide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Introduce un numero: ");
        num= entrada.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) { 

            System.out.println(); 

            for (int j = 0; j < num-i-1; ++j) { 

                } 

            for (int j = 0; j < 2*i+1; ++j){ 

                System.out.print("*"); 
                } 

        } 

        System.out.println(); 

            }
    }
```

me sale esto:

```
Introduce un numero: 7

*
***
*****
*******
*********
***********
*************
```

Comment: Mas alla de que te dieron una respuesta, es muy importante que cuando copias y pegues codigo, entiendas que hace linea por linea. Tu error se debe a que no entendes lo que hace. Tener la solucion a mano no va a hacer que entiendas el codigo. Tenelo en cuenta para el proximo ejercicio que te den. la solucion tenes que construirla entendiendo lo que se hace.

Comment: lo hare la proxima vez, este era un poco mas dificil de lo que suelo hacer

Comment: Y el proximo va a ser todavia mas dificil, esa es la idea de resolver los ejercicios ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo que en el tema de programacion, en cuanto menos copies mejor. Dicho esto...

El problema que tienes es sencillo. El codigo en si esta bien, pero te falta añadir un salto de linea con espacio en uno de los bucles que anidados. Imagino que te lo han pasado mal, o no te fijaste bien.

Te dejo el codigo, miralo y haz pruebas. Cambia cosas y asi vas viendo los cambios que se van realizando para comprenderlo mejor.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Piramide {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Introduce un numero: ");
        num= entrada.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) { 

            System.out.println(); 

            for (int j = 0; j < num-i-1; ++j) { 

                System.out.print(" "); //TENIAS QUE AÑADIR ESTE DE AQUI

                } 

            for (int j = 0; j < 2*i+1; ++j){ 

                System.out.print("*"); 
                } 

        } 

        System.out.println(); 

            }
    }
```

Comment: vayaa no se ma habia ocurrido eso. gracias saraidaa

Comment: @Jaime31 recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas en tu código es calcular los espacios necesarios para que vaya centrando los *, es algo que no habías agregado:

```
    ...
    ...
    for (int j = 0; j < num-i-1; ++j) { 
          System.out.print(" "); 
    } 
    ... 
    ...
```

esto realiza el cambio:

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Introduce un numero: ");
int num= entrada.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) { 
        System.out.println(); 

        for (int j = 0; j < num-i-1; ++j) { 
              System.out.print(" "); 
        } 

        for (int j = 0; j < 2*i+1; ++j){ 
            System.out.print("*"); 
        } 
}
```

---

Otra forma de realizar la pirámide, como comentaba,solo necesitas en tu código calcular los espacios necesarios para que vaya centrando los *:

```
   Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduce un numero: ");
    int num= entrada.nextInt();

    //numero de espacios 
    int spaces = 2 * num - 2; 

    //Bucle que itera de acuerdo al numero de rows
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) { 

        for (int j = 0; j < spaces; j++) 
            System.out.print(" "); 

        //Decrementa espacios
        spaces = spaces - 1; 

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++ ) {               
            // printing stars 
            System.out.print("* "); 
        } 

         //Crean nueva linea mediante println
        System.out.print("\n"); 
    }
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]